# By mathematical induction prove that?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction, education

> $\frac{1}{n + 1} + \frac{1}{n + 2} + \frac{1}{n + 3} + ..... +\frac{1}{3(n) + 1} >  1 $;

Here in this sequence after checking the basis for n = 1 , i.e $\frac{1}{4} > 1$, Which cannot be true;

> I think I am wrong at some point , If yes then how can we prove this sequence by mathematical induction?

Comment: For $n=\color{blue}{1}$ the desired statement reads $\frac{1}{\color{blue}1 + 1}+\frac{1}{\color{blue}1 + 2}+\frac{1}{\color{blue}1 + 3}>1$  noting that the final term in the summation $\frac{1}{\color{blue}1 + 3}$ can be rewritten as $\frac{1}{3\cdot \color{blue}1 + 1}$.  Notice, $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}$ is indeed greater than $1$.

Comment: Okay, so further, how do I solve the inequality ?

Comment: The very first step is to understand what the statement is that you are trying to prove.  It does not appear that you have taken this step.

Comment: And how am I going to take that step , If people instead of explaining, start criticizing you ?

Comment: @user83869 You were confused about the base case for $n=1$, and that confusion got sorted out. The next step is to continue your induction with induction hypothesis and induction step.

Comment: The statement you are trying to prove in words is that for all natural numbers $n$, the sum of fractions whose numerators are $1$ and denominators range from $n+1$ on up to $3n+1$ and every natural between will add up to be strictly greater than $1$.  The base case for $n=1$ says that $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}>1$ noting that $1+1=2$ and that $3\cdot 1 + 1 = 4$.  Meanwhile for $n=2$ it says that $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}>1$ noting that $2+1=3$ and that $3\cdot 2 + 1 = 7$.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=1$ we need to check that
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}>1$$ or
$$\frac{13}{12}>1.$$
Let $$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{3n+1}>1.$$ Thus,
$$\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}+...+\frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}+\frac{1}{3n+3}+\frac{1}{3n+4}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}+\frac{1}{3n+3}+\frac{1}{3n+4}-\frac{1}{n+1}>$$
$$>1+\frac{1}{3n+2}+\frac{1}{3n+3}+\frac{1}{3n+4}-\frac{1}{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{3n+2}+\frac{1}{3n+4}-\frac{2}{3(n+1)}=$$
$$=1+\frac{2}{3(n+1)(3n+2)(3n+4)}>1$$
and we are done!

Comment: Can I do this by assuming $n = K$ and then $n = k + 1$

Comment: @user83869 Yes, of course! It's the same.

Comment: Okay I got that . And where did that $\frac{1}{n + 1} $ in the second step ,come from ?

Comment: @user83869 It there is in our assumption. I added and I deducted it. See please better.